# Setting up Ime Action as search has no effect on fire tv

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, amazon-fire-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I have an Outlined Text Field to which my ImeAction is set as ImeAction.Search.The search action is visible for the soft keyboard in Android TV But does not work for fire Tv.Any solution for this.

passed KeyboardActions.Default.copy(imeAction = ImeAction.Search